# Pass -express-flash-messages- in an EJS file

Tags: express, ejs

I've a user controller which has a basic authentication logic. I'm using an `ejs` view engine . I'm finding trouble accessing these flash messages in my view, i.e. `.ejs` file. What should be the right approach. I dug through some information and found out that we can pass `parameters` during a `res.redirect`. However, I don't want to do that, since it will appear in the URL. Is there a solution to this, something like what `pug` engine has.

```
 if (!user || !user.authenticate(req.body.password)) {
  req.flash('error', 'Invalid email or password!')
  res.redirect('/login')

  return
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass your flash messages to your views using **res.locals** object:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  res.render('login', { errorMessage: req.flash('error')[0] });
});
```

Then in your view:

```
<% if (errorMessage) { %>
  <div class="error">
    <p><%= errorMessage %></p> <!-- Invalid email or password! -->
  </div>
<% } %>
```